# OpenSSL Wrong version number on Ubuntu SSH

Tags: nginx, ssl, openssl

I'm setting my nginx to listen to port 8080 here's my config file and it works on when I'm accessing with `http` e.g `http://myweb.com:8080/api/`.

```
server {
    listen 8080;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_ssl_server_name on;
    }
}
```

However when I try to access it with `https` on Insomnia it returns `SSL connect error`.
When I try  `curl https://myweb.com:8080 --verbose`
It returns something like this:

```
*   Trying {myipadress}:8080...
* Connected to myweb.com (ipaddress) port 8080 (#0)
* ALPN: offers h2,http/1.1
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
*  CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
*  CApath: none
* OpenSSL/3.0.8: error:0A00010B:SSL routines::wrong version number
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) OpenSSL/3.0.8: error:0A00010B:SSL routines::wrong version number
```

I've been configuring for two days and IDK what's wrong, does anybody have similar issue?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This error is due to simply using `https://` on a target and port, which is configured for plain `http://`.

HTTPS and HTTP are different protocols, which need to be configured on different ports and also need different configuration. Specially support for HTTPS needs also the configuration of certificates on the server side. See [nginx documentation](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html) for how to configure HTTPS.

Comment: Should I put the ssl_certificate on port 8080 as well ?

Comment: @stanley355: to cite myself with the relevant part in bold: *".... which __need to be configured on different ports__ and also need different configuration"*